# Freeswitch: Lua performance bottleneck after importing http.request

Tags: lua, freeswitch

We use Freeswitch stack with 4000 channels to send IVR calls. The logic is written in Lua. We need to send a POST request whenever a call gets picked up. For this purpose we are using [lua-http](https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http) package. Both the functionalities, i.e. outbound calling and sending POST request are implemented in same Lua file. When we import lua-http package (require "http.request"), we observe high CPU utilization (more than 95%). This affects outbound calls. We have also observed that, whenever number of threads importing the library cross 1500, system starts slowing down. One possible solution is to restrict number of threads but that would reduce number of outbound calls. Is there anything else we can do to remove this bottleneck?

System configuration:

1. Operating system: Debian,
2. 4 core CPU, 16G RAM

Comment: You may use queue in freeswitch if it's feasible with your solution. https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_amqp